# Electronjs window.require not a function

Tags: electron

I'm using create-react-app (react-scripts v3.0.0) and electronjs (v5.0.1). I'm trying to pass events from the renderer to main process using the 'icpMain' module [as described here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), but get the error `window.require` is not a function for the line

```
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
```

How can I get `require` into the global scope in the renderer process? Or is there another way of communicating between the main and renderer process?

Edit:

I've tried removing the react build entirely and get the same results simply using the electron example code in index.html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like adding the preference:

```
var mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
  }
});
```

is needed to enable `require` in the renderer process.

Answer (score 21):

Since Electron 12, contextIsolation is be enabled by default, the implication being that require() cannot be used in the renderer process unless contextIsolation is false, more info in this link https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-contextisolation-defaults-to-true

So include the following:

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
}
```

Comment: Answers like this save hours in debugging time. Thank you!

Comment: After a thousand try, here I am. Thanks a lot! Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure webpreferences is like this.

```
 webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you have to set `nodeIntegration` to `true` in your BrowserWindow webPreferences since the version [5.0.0](https://electronjs.org/releases/stable#release-notes-for-v500) the default values of nodeIntegration and webviewTag are false to improve security. Electron associated PR: [16235](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16235)

Answer (score 2):

I fix this issue to add `webPreferences:{ nodeIntegration: true,preload: '${__dirname}/preload.js}',` in `electron.js` file and add `preload.js` file in your directory (I added in `/public` directory where my `electron.js` file exists)

**electron.js**

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
 title: 'Electron App',
 height: 650,
 width: 1140,
 webPreferences: { 
  nodeIntegration: true,
  preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
  webSecurity: false 
 },
 show: false,
 frame: true,
 closeable: false,
 resizable: false,
 transparent: false,
 center: true,
});

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // prints "ping"
  event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
});
```

**preload.js**

in preload.js file just add below line:

```
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

**ReactComponent.js**

Write below code in your component function i.e: **myTestHandle()**

```
myTestHandle = () => {
  window.ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg); // prints "pong"
  });
  window.ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
}
myTestHandle();
```

or call `myTestHandle` function anywhere in your component

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `contextIsolation` to false!
But use the `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` to add all what you need into the `window` object.

main.js

```js
webPreferences: { 
  contextIsolation: true,
  preload: path.join(__dirname, '../preload.js')
}
```

preload.js

```js
const {
  contextBridge,
  ipcRenderer,
  ...
} = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  ipcRenderer,
  ...
});
```

Don't use `require()` in your React app.

If you are using React with typescript you should declare all extra fields like this:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: any;
    require: any;  // this is a fix for the "window.require is not a function" error. But you don't need it anymore.
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = window.electron;
```

Important: Don't try to expose the whole lib. Expose only what you need.

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", electron); // Error
```