# Electron window will not minimise or close

Tags: javascript, python, electron, eel

I am building an electron app with the use of eel as well, although I am not sure that is relevant here. I recently came back to this project, and I'm sure it was working before. Everything works except for the minimise and close buttons which are custom ones.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="title-bar">
    <div id="title-bar-btns">
        <button id="min-btn" onclick="window_minimise()">&#x2014;</button>
        <button id="close-btn" onclick="window_close()">&#x2715;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
function window_minimise(){
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();
}

function window_close(){
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    eel.quit_app();
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
}
```

And the Python code

```
@eel.expose
def quit_app():
    sys.exit(0)
```

I tried running it in my browser via http://localhost:8000/html/index.html and when I click minimise I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at window_minimise (index.js:111)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:18)

And close

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at window_close (index.js:117)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:19)

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my electron main.js file

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 748, icon:'web/images/favicon-32x32.png', resizable: false,
  frame: false, show: false, backgroundColor: '#171717'}) // Needs to be changed based on theme
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  mainWindow.show()
})
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/html/index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active unti, l the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

There are some errors in it (missing semicolons and `let mainWindow`), but those errors are also in the electron-quick-start main.js so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56289565/1907797

You have to set `nodeIntegration` to `true` in your BrowserWindow webPreferences since the version [5.0.0](https://electronjs.org/releases/stable#release-notes-for-v500) the default values of nodeIntegration and webviewTag are false to improve security. Electron associated PR: [16235](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16235)

```js
const mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean in my main.js file? So `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 748, icon:'web/images/favicon-32x32.png', resizable: false,
  frame: false, show: false, backgroundColor: '#171717', webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}})`

Comment: Yep, it should fix it, do you still have the exact same error ?

Comment: Did you restart your electron process ?
And in your devtools console if you type `require` it retrurns `undefined` ?

Comment: I restarted my python file which should execute the electron process. It says `VM55:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Oh yes you are using eel, so it's not exactly electron. I think you don't need to use require and remote but simply expose a python function that call mainWindow.close from your python code.

Comment: I had this working before so I think the issue is due to a change in Electron (I last worked on it about 9 months ago). Perhaps something in my main.js file is different to the new version or something similar.

Comment: Yes as explained in my answer electron made few changes about it in electron 5.0.0 (April 24, 2019), that's why I told you to add nodeIntegration in the webPreferences. Maybe you can check on the eel side, or try to downgrade to an older electron version.

Comment: The thing is, I'm only on version 2.0.0. I don't think eel has any involvement and I wouldn't be sure how to add `mainwindow.close` to it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable nodeIntegration in index.html, then only you can use require in renderer page

Comment: How do I do that?