# How to bring window into foreground in electron-vue

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-vue

I want to bring the main `BrowserWindow` into the foreground after a countdown finished. When calling `electron.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().show()` in `App.vue`, i am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFocusedWindow' of undefined
```

`electron` is being imported via `const electron = window.require("electron");` in `App.vue`

Comment: have you tried to set nodeIntegration to true as in the following example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267851/4858916

Comment: @MazenSharkawy I've already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid doing this part on the renderer process all together, and do it in a cleaner way at the same time, you can try to move calling the getFocusedWindow().show() to the electron side.
By doing something like this:

App.vue

```
 let ipcRenderer = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer
 ipcRenderer.send("bring-to-foreground");
```

electron.js

```
ipcMain.on("bring-to-foreground", (e) => {
  electron.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().show();
}
```

I also think that you should use keep your mainwindow so you don't use getFocusedWindow because according to the docs it might return null if the window is not focused in the first place. Like this:

```
let mainWindow;
const createWindow = () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})
    //rest of the function goes here
}
```

so you can then simply do:

```
mainwindow.show()
```