# How to open system browser from electron container

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have created react app after that i added electron module to react app.Actually i am trying open OS browser from electron container which has react app.I am using latest electron version(12). I tried so many ways but i am not able to figure it out.

code:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow  = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule:true,
    }
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
import React from "react";
const electron = window.require("electron");

function App() {
  const openBrowser = () => {};

  return <div onClick={openBrowser}>{isRenderer ? "Electron" : "react"}</div>;
}

export default App;


×
TypeError: window.require is not a function
Module.<anonymous>
src/App.tsx:3
  1 | import React from "react";
  2 | var isRenderer = require("is-electron-renderer");
> 3 | const electron = window.require("electron");
  4 | 
  5 | function App() {
  6 |   const openBrowser = () => {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? I use this to open new browser windows.

```
const googleLink = `https://www.google.com`
window.open(googleLink, ‘_blank’)
```

Comment: TypeError: window.require is not a function
Module.<anonymous>, i am getting this error

Comment: i am trying open url in OS browser from electron

Comment: you do not need that line unless you are using anything from electron. Electron itself is a chrome browser, using `window.open` is sufficient to open up a new window

Comment: i have requirement like that, i need to access electron shell in react code do u know ?

Comment: Please kindly edit the question title and question post to reflect your question, since it's not related to opening of new window. I can provide you with an answer after.

Comment: i changed the title, should i need to use preload.js for getting shell in electron build

Comment: window.require = require

Comment: then try setting webpreference `contextIsolation: false`

Comment: did everything i added all flags in webprefernce

Comment: what version electron u using?

Comment: you read this post i suppose https://stackoverflow.com/a/67000521/2822041 ?